# video chat application on node.js with webRTC( socket.io) works fine on localhost but gives error on network

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, streaming, chat

I am making a video chat application on node.js with WebRTC(socket.io). This application runs fine on localhost but gives error while running on my network with my IP address. Also, I tried it on Heroku but error remained same

---

Only Top of my server looks like

```
   const express = require("express");
    const socket = require("socket.io");
    const app = express();
    
    //Starts the server
    
    let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT||4000, function () {
      console.log("Server is running");
    });
    
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
    
    //Upgrades the server to accept websockets.
    
    let io = socket(server);
    
    //Triggered when a client is connected.
    
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
      console.log("User Connected :" + socket.id);
```

---

Top part of client side is

```
let socket = io.connect("//192.168.1.73:4000");
let divVideoChatLobby = document.getElementById("video-chat-lobby");
let divVideoChat = document.getElementById("video-chat-room");
let joinButton = document.getElementById("join");
let userVideo = document.getElementById("user-video");
let peerVideo = document.getElementById("peer-video");
let roomInput = document.getElementById("roomName");
let roomName;
let creator = false;
let rtcPeerConnection;
let userStream;

// Contains the stun server URL we will be using.
let iceServers = {
  iceServers: [
    { urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"},
    { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
  ],
};
```

---

Error on running on running server on 192.168.1.73:4000 is

```
chat.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined

    at f.<anonymous> (chat.js:37)
    at f.r.emit (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at f.value (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at f.value (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at f.value (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at b.<anonymous> (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at b.r.emit (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at b.value (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at n.<anonymous> (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)
    at n.r.emit (socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6)

(anonymous) @ chat.js:37
r.emit @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
r.emit @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
r.emit @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
r.emit @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
r.emit @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
value @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
ws.onmessage @ socket.io-3.0.1.min.js:6
```

---

on Heroku error looks like

GET https://projectnepflix.herokuapp.com:4000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NVEwhoG net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on Chrome

git repo sample : https://github.com/innovatoraakash/nepflix

Comment: Your error is: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' but you didn't provide the code that actually calls getUserMedia. Please, share the part that does that so I can look at why it happens.

Comment: https://github.com/innovatoraakash/nepflix here is the repo. Client is in public

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same problem a while ago.

This note from [getUserMedia documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) describes the reason for your issue on the server:

> Note: If the current document isn't loaded securely, navigator.mediaDevices will be undefined, and you cannot use getUserMedia(). See Security for more information on this and other security issues related to using getUserMedia()

This means that, you have run your app with HTTPS (unless you're localhost), or else `navigator.mediaDevices` will be undefined as stated above, hence when you try to call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It was difficult to make my public IP HTTPS over my network so I changed the

```
let socket = io.connect("//192.168.1.73:4000");
```

line with

```
var socket = io.connect(window.location.href);
```

This was the reason for the error in Heroku and I Tested finely over Heroku as it runs over https so navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedi does not crash